# Calling a function when promise returns success or failure

Tags: javascript, promise

Let's say I have code set up like so:

**App1.js**

```
function doStuff() {
  axios.get("/api/endpoint").then(response => {
    // do App1.js-specific stuff
  }).catch(error => {
    // do App1.js-specific error handling
  });
}
```

**App2.js**

```
function invokeStuff(){
  doStuff();
}

function doSomethingOnSuccess(){...}
function doSomethingOnFailure(){...}
```

In App2.js **I want to be able to invoke doSomethingOnSuccess() or doSomethingOnFailure() as soon as the axios call from App1 returns**. How can I structure my code to achieve this assuming those two functions cannot be moved into App1.js?

Comment: Your `doStuff` function should *`return`* the promise that it creates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't fully handle the error inside `doStuff`, you should rethrow it (or throw a new Error):

```
function doStuff() {
  return axios.get("/api/endpoint").then(response => {
    // do App1.js-specific stuff
  }).catch(error => {
    // do App1.js-specific error handling
    throw error; // rethrow
  });
}
```

App2.js :

```
function invokeStuff(){
  doStuff().then(doSomethingOnSuccess, doSomethingOnFailue);
}

function doSomethingOnSuccess(){...}
function doSomethingOnFailure(){...}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have doStuff return the promise, and then use that promise to chain additional .then calls. You've got a catch in doStuff, so that will get first crack at handling errors. If there's anything you fail to handle, you can rethrow it

```
function doStuff() {
  return axios.get("/api/endpoint").then(response => {
    // do App1.js-specific stuff
  }).catch(error => {
    // do App1.js-specific error handling
    return Promise.reject(error); // if not handled
  });
}

//...

function invokeStuff(){
  doStuff()
    .then(doSomethingOnSuccess)
    .catch(doSomethingOnFailure)
}
```